# Google Apps is now called G Suite

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-request

Google has renamed Google Apps to G Suite:

> We created Google Apps to help people everywhere work and innovate
>   together, so organizations can move faster and achieve more. On
>   September 29, 2016, we introduced  a new name that better reflects
>   this mission: G Suite.
>
> The new name and logo will appear in the Google Admin console, online
>   help, and email notifications. G Suite is still the same all-in-one
>   solution that you use every day, with the same powerful tools like
>   Gmail, Docs, Drive, and Calendar. Your services and pricing remain the
>   same.

Source [About the name change from Google Apps to G Suite](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7126147?hl=en)

I have created [g-suite](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/g-suite):

> G Suite is the new name for Google Apps. It is a suite of products for business clients of Google. Unless these products specifically involve your browser or computer software, questions about Google Suite are considered off-topic and should be asked on webapps....

We should also create a synonym from [google-apps](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-apps) to [g-suite](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/g-suite).

Edit: Just bumping this.  The question anchoring the new tag was migrated.  Didn't want the new tag to disappear before the synonym was created.  I manually edited the [google-apps](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-apps) tag on another question that didn't look like a migration candidate to [g-suite](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/g-suite) (per comments).

Edit 2: Just noticed that no action has happened on this yet.  It seems like a no-brainer, and the question has a net +10 (one downvote, which might reflect that the literal wording of the question differs from its current state of affairs).  Is there an issue preventing this from moving forward?  FYI, the vast majority of upvotes were received after the proposed action was revised and clarified in comments.  Does the question, itself, need to be updated to accurately reflect the desired action?

Comment: The middle options makes the most sense

Comment: I looked through a few [tag:google-apps] questions, and I'm surprised how many are on topic. But there were quite a few that are off topic as well, and some that assume that google-apps is, in fact, the add ons in Chrome.

Comment: It's called G Suite, not Google Suite.

Comment: It looks like G Suite is the official name.  Suggestion: [g-suite] rather than [google-suite] as the new primary tag; no [google-suite] tag, but include the Google explanation in the wiki excerpt; synonomize [google-apps] with [g-suite].

Comment: @fixer1234 [g-suite] created (with Google explanation). I don't have enough tag rep to create the synonyms :/

Comment: @Flimm Done :) .

Comment: @fixer1234 I would have made the synonym but I don't have enough tag rep. I think it might need a mod ...

Comment: @fixer1234 I've pinged for a mod in https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114/ask-a-super-user-moderator to create the synonym for us.

Comment: Question updated as per comments.

Comment: Do we want existing google-apps to be merged with g-suite, I.e. the tag to be renamed on existing questions, or do we *just* want the synonym?

Comment: @Mokubai I suppose a merge makes sense together with the synonym.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merged and synonymised.

```
updating post history, 168 rows affected (pipe delimited) 
updating posts, 136 rows affected (pipe delimited) 
updating PostTags associations, 136 rows affected 
updating Documentation tag proposal commitments, 0 rows affected 
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected 
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected tag 
remapping of [g-suite] and [google-apps] complete! 
remapping 0 synonyms 
31 favorite and ignored tags remapped! 
28 tracked tag badges were remapped! 
Tag Synonym google-apps -> g-suite was approved!
```

Comment: Thanks - that earned me a new badge - taxonomist :)

Comment: So that's why you wanted it! Sneaky badge hunters at it again... ;)

Comment: great, but I also noticed that the g-suite questions are distributed across superuser, webapps, and serverfault.

Comment: @Tom And? Each site has a different scope and the applicability is different. It is up to each site to handle changes as they see fit.